# How to set the values from one hashmap to another hashmap?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

```
ClassData customClass= customclass.get("John" + 1 );
ClassData currentClass= currentclass.get("John");
currentClass = customClass;

public Map<String, ClassData> currentclass = new HashMap<String, ClassData>();
public Map<String, ClassData> customclass = new HashMap<String, ClassData>();
```

Is this possible to set the ClassData of customclass to currentclass in this way?
Or should I set / get it for each attribute of ClassData? or what other way is really efficient, without I remove any values of a other hashmap key.

Comment: calling the hashmap a name having class is quite annoying, you might want to change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't change the maps at all. If you want to set a single entry in one map to the value from another, the easiest thing is to do it explicitly:

```
currentclass.put("John", customclass.get("John" + 1));
```

However, if you want to copy all the key/value pairs of one map into another, you can use the `putAll` method of `Map`:

```
currentclass.putAll(customclass);
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense Thanks, what would happen with currentClass = customClass;? i'm curious.

Comment: @user1621988 - You'd end up with `currentClass` and `customClass` referencing the identical object, as if you had executed `currentClass = customClass = customclass.get("John" + 1);`. The `currentclass` map won't be affected at all. (By the way, you should probably do yourself a favor and rename the maps to something like `currentClassMap` and `customClassMap` -- it's hard to distinguish two variables by the change of case somewhere in the middle of the variable name.)